# Visualize large dimension clusters in R using k-means

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, k-means

I have a dataset with several rows and 5 dimensions (all numeric). After normalization, I applied the k-means algorithm in order to clusterize the data.

```
clus2_k3<-kmeans(clus2,centers=3)
```

After this step I would like to visualize the result, but as it has more than 3 dimensions it is not possible to use 2D or 3D plot.

Is there any command or algorithm to plot it, or if not, an alternative way to reduce the number of dimensions without losing the information from the substracted ones?

Comment: You may try to reduce the dimensionality to 3 or even 2, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis, with `stats::prcomp()` or `stats::princomp()`. Oh, it looks like the `stats::prcomp()` is preferred: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20101/what-is-the-difference-between-r-functions-prcomp-and-princomp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it is completely unreadable as a comment...

```
require(ggplot2)
data("iris")

pca_res <- prcomp(as.matrix(iris[, 1:4]), center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
plot_data <- cbind(as.data.frame(pca_res$x[, 1:2]), labels = iris[, 5])

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, colour = labels)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Edit: You may try different combinations of `center` and `scale.` params, as e.g. this set looks a bit better with both set to `FALSE`:

[image]

#### Edit:

To see the "loss of information" mentioned in the comment one may use the `summary()` function:

```
summary(pca_res)

# Importance of components:
#                           PC1    PC2     PC3     PC4
# Standard deviation     1.7084 0.9560 0.38309 0.14393
# Proportion of Variance 0.7296 0.2285 0.03669 0.00518
# Cumulative Proportion  0.7296 0.9581 0.99482 1.00000
```

Here PC1 and PC2 stand for 0.96 of cumulative prop. of variance, which means 96% of "information" is stored in those two components.

Comment: It is really an interesting option to use this algebraic tool to reduce the number of dimensions. Maybe it is also recommended to make a previous analysis of data variance in each dimension in order to observe if the loss of information is relevant when suppressing dimensions.

Comment: For the "loss of information" the `summary(pca_res)` could be useful, as it gives you the cumulative variance for the components - please see the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly standard to do pairwise plots, e.g.

[image: Iris data scatter plot]

This is 4 dimensional data. The same approach still works for 5 dimensions, too.

See the R command [`pairs`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/pairs.html) from your R manual for details.

Comment: I think this is a good option for the dataset I have because it has a small number of dimentions. But do you have an alternative representation when the number of dimentions is higher?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plot function only but you need to specify particular column which `K-means` throws, it will throws result as list with name `cluster`.

Try this code:

```
plot(clus2_k3$cluster)
```